# HTTP/2 for HAproxy and nginx

Tags: nginx, haproxy, http2

This answer does not answer my question:

[How can I enable HTTP/2 on HAProxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656406/how-can-i-enable-http-2-on-haproxy)

What I have is huge site with many servers. Most of them are supported by one HAproxy which is set for http and https traffic, on one separate server. Also per each server it hosts own nginx which also have two traffics supported (http, https) with certs.

My problem now is to add HTTP/2 to general traffic - beside HTTP/1.1. HAproxy is routing all the traffic without certificates. Nginx is serving certs. Nginx is mostly 1.24.0. HAproxy 2.0.2.

I am adding options to config files:

```
haproxy: bind ... proto h2
haproxy: bind ... ssl alpn h2,http/1.1
nginx: listen ... http2
```

but it does not work. I get 502, empty responses or even the sites are not loading in web browser (request sent, response never arrives). Seems like HAproxy will not accept `ssl alpn` without given cert.

How this could be configured when HAproxy can't serve certs?